# Actualizar columna A en tabla X con base en valor de columna A en tabla Y

Tags: sql-server, update

En un servidor SQL 2012 tengo que hacer una actualización masiva (registro por registro) de una columna A en la tabla X con base en el valor que tenga esa misma columna en la tabla Y.  La llave es un numero de serie, ¿Cómo puedo hacer esto?

Answer (score 1):

Segun comentas, esta seria la consulta:

```
UPDATE tx SET tx.A=ty.A
FROM x AS tx
INNER JOIN Y AS ty
ON tx.Key=ty.Key
```

Comment: Gracias Guillermo, eso es exactamente lo que necesitaba.